# Is installing Windows on Macbook Pro for Game development good and efficient

Tags: mac, windows, development

I have a Macbook PRO, new to game development. Looks like Windows is the recommended OS for game development. Will installing Windows in mac with bootcamp assistantfor Game development good. Is anyone here is doing that? Or continue to use MacOS for game development. Im going to be using Unreal Game Engine.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at it objectively, then yes installing Windows in BootCamp is both "good" and "efficient" in the sense that (a) this is a supported configuration for your computer that will not "break" anything, and (b) you'll be able to make full use of the computer's hardware's performance.

On the other hand, I don't see you couldn't keep using macOS for game development as well. There's no rule or general recommendation that Windows is always "best for game development" - far from it.

If you're planning to develop a game for the Mac or for iOS users, I would stick with the Mac. If you're developing a game only for Windows users, there's good arguments for running on the same target as your own users.